# Jamie the robot repair and use

Tags: wasteland-2-directors-cut

I understand that I can repair Jamie the Robot, but every time I try that, it just fix 1HP.
Since he took 60HP on the last battle, it would take me a lifetime fixing it.

Is there a way to fix all its HP?

Or is he condemned to die quickly?